# functions from rn to rm

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question that I am really confused on how to solve:

Let $$z_1 = 2y_1+3y_2$$ $$z_2=y_1y_2^{2}$$ $$y_1=e^{x_1}+x_2$$ $$y_2=e^{(x_1-x_2)}+x_1$$ Use the chain rule to find $\frac{\partial{z_i}}{\partial{x_j}}$ for $i,j=1,2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

All I know is the chain rule which states:

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial\bar{x_1}}\frac{\partial{\bar{x_i}}}{\partial{x_i}}+...+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial\bar{x_n}}\frac{\partial{\bar{x_n}}}{\partial{x_i}}$$

But how am I supposed to get it in terms of $x$ and $y$? I've been out of practice for a very long time so even basic things I am forgetting, does anyone have a solution to this question that can explain what to do?

Comment: Did you mean $$\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$$ ?

Comment: Step back and look at which variables depend on which.  Here $z_1,z_2$ depend on $y_1,y_2$, and $y_1,y_2$ depend on $x_1,x_2$.  So you could use the chain rule, or (perhaps as a check) you could substitute to get $z_1,z_2$ directly in terms of $x_1,x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, in the case $i=2, j=1$ the chain rule says

$$ \dfrac{\partial z_2}{\partial x_1} = \dfrac{\partial z_2}{\partial y_1} \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} + \dfrac{\partial z_2}{\partial y_2} \dfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} $$

Can you find each of the derivatives on the right side, and express them in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: can you please explain how you applied the chain rule? I think I can compute the derivatives and express them in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, thank you!

Comment: For my question, I just used your example as a template because for my question $i=1$ and $j=2$ and this is how I tried to solve it:
$\frac{\partial{z_1}}{\partial{x_2}} = 2*1+3(-e^{(x_1-x_2)})$ Is this correct? And I guess I don't know how to express it in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, how can I do that?

Comment: I was able to understand your application of the chain rule, but I'm still unsure on how to express the answer I got for $\frac{\partial{z_1}}{\partial{x_2}}$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$. I know that means to isolate both $x_1$ and $x_2$ but how would I do that in this specific case?